# LAN connection not working when cable plugged after removal

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, lan, network-adapter

I am facing a weird problem recently. When I reboot my computer with the LAN cable plugged in, it's connected and everything works fine. But when I remove the cable and plug it in again, it detects LAN but shows no internet access (And in 1 or 2 cases, it didn't detect LAN too).

Each time I plug out my LAN cable I have to reboot my system to get connected again. I even tried disabling and re-enabling the LAN adapter, but the problem still persists. My OS is Windows 7. Can someone help me out on this?

We use static IPs only. Each LAN cable is assigned a static IP. `ipconfig /renew` has no effect.

Comment: have you tried disabling power management on the nic? if you run 'ipconfig /renew' does that have any impact? have you tried a static IP?

Comment: from netowrk center, select 'change adapter settings' and right click the interface you want -> Properties. then click the Configure button. go to the Power Management tab, and you should see a checkbox. the exact text depends on your NIC driver software.

Comment: This is an old post, and it looks like you solved it.  Can you post your solution as an answer and accept it?

Comment: @fixer1234 didn't solve it then. Ended up "not removing the cable" unless laptop to be moved out of room.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is going into the network setting in the control panel and right-click on ur ethernet adapter and go into the properties-configure-power management-uncheck the option to shut down to save power option (or whatever it says with regards to saving power) and that's it. problem solved.